# Using ajax with multiple selects

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building a portfolio page and created some filters to user organize the portfolio list. The filters are dropdown lists, like that:

```
<select name="category" id="filter-category" class="chosen-select">
       <option value="0">All</option>
       <option value="1">Magazine</option>
       <option value="2">Books</option>
       ...  
</select>
```

There are another select for client and for projects order.

I send this values using jquery ajax. Here is an excerpt:

```
$('.chosen-select').change( function(){
var client= $('#filter-client option:selected').val();
var category = $('#filter-category option:selected').val();
var order = $('#filter-order option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    data: ({client: client, category : category, order : order}),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/portfolio.php',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    } 
});

});
```

My question is: I need to create a query for each situation? One for when the user selects only the client, one for when selecting the customer and category, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do that. You send the data of the three filters (combobox) and in the `php/portfolio.php` you find what filters user changed.
for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE ....."
if($_POST['client']!="")
    $sql.=" AND client=".$_POST['client'];
if($_POST['category']!="")
    $sql.=" AND category=".$_POST['category'];
...
```

is that what you want?